# Change magento 1 header on mobile

Tags: php, html, header

Currently my /template/page/html/header.pthml contains twice the topMenu.

This because we load an entire different inner html for mobile, instead of the desktop version. But this also means that the menu is loaded twice in our code.
We hide the menu by using css based on the screen size.

But instead I want to load the menu only once and display it depending on the screensize. How can I achieve that?

CODE of header.phtml:

```
<header class="header-wrapper <?php if(Mage::getModel('cms/block')->load('header_notice_alert')->getIsActive()):?>header-notice-active<?php endif;?>">
    <div class="header-container">
        <div id="mobile-sticky" class="mobile-header main-header visible-tablet">
            <div class="header-content">
                <div class="left-header-menu">
                    <div class="menu-sidebar-wrap">
                        <div class="link-sidebar">
                            <a href="#" class="menu-bars-link sidebar-link" data-show="sidebar-container" data-side="left">
                                <span><?php echo $this->__('Menu');?></span>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('') ?>" title="<?php echo $this->getLogoAlt() ?>" class="logo">
                    <img width="130" height="68" class="x1" src='/'  alt="<?php echo $this->getLogoAlt() ?>" />
                </a>
                <div class="right-header-menu">
                    <div class="header-maincart">
                        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('cart_header'); ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="right-header-menu">
                    <div class="header-quote">
                        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('miniquote_head'); ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="main-header" class="main-header hidden-tablet">
                <div id="header" class="header_<?php echo $header_type;?>_wrapper sticky-header">
                <div class="container-red-header">
                    <a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('') ?>" title="<?php echo $this->getLogoAlt() ?>" class="logo">
                        <img width="130" height="68" class="x1" src='/'  alt="<?php echo $this->getLogoAlt() ?>" />
                    </a>
                    <div class="right-header-menu">
                        <div class="header-search">
                            <div class="search-container">
                                <div class="overwrite-setting">
                                    <i class="sf-icon-search"></i>
                                </div>
                                <div class="switcher-content">
                                    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('topSearch') ?>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="header-quote">
                            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('miniquote_head'); ?>
                        </div>
                        <div class="header-maincart">
                            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('cart_header'); ?>
                        </div>
                        <div class="header-setting">
                            <div class="setting-switcher switcher-wrap">
                                    <?php if ($this->helper('customer')->isLoggedIn() ):?>
                                    <div class="overwrite-setting loggedin">
                                        <i class="sf-icon-account loggedin"></i>
                                    </div>
                                    <?php else:?>
                                    <div class="overwrite-setting">
                                        <i class="sf-icon-account"></i>
                                    </div>
                                    <?php endif;?>
                                <div class="switcher-content">
                                    <?php if($toplink):?>
                                        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('topLinks') ?>
                                    <?php endif;?>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="wrapper-top-menu container">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                                <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('topMenu') ?>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="header-notice">
            <div class="container">
                <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('headerNotice'); ?>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('topContainer'); ?>
    </div>
</header>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create a separate mobile theme with a design exception. It looks at the user-agent, not the screen size. You can set an design exception at System > Configuration > General > Design > Themes, click at Add Exception. For "matched expression", you can add something like

```
iPhone|iPod|BlackBerry|Palm|Googlebot-Mobile|Mobile|mobile|mobi|Windows Mobile|Safari Mobile|Android|Opera Mini
```

"Value" would be the name of the mobile theme.

I found this article that seems to explain it in more detail: http://magebase.com/magento-tutorials/magento-design-exceptions-explained/